# Matlab Builder NE Toolbox compatibility

Tags: matlab, matlab-compiler

I'm considering using Matlab Builder NE to create a DLL for .NET environment.
I know that some Matlab features don't work with Builder NE (ex: simulink).

Does Curve Fitting Toolbox is eligible for using with Builder NE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this page for a list of supported functions and toolboxes:

> [MATLAB Compiler - Support for MATLAB and Toolboxes](http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/supported/compiler_support.html)

So basically all functions from the Curve Fitting toolbox are supported to be deployed using MATLAB Compiler products, except of course any GUI tools.